# In Natural Deduction can I use a negation introduction when I already have (∃x)(Gx∧¬Gx)?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

In a Natural Deduction, I want to get ¬(∃x)(Gx).
So I assume (∃x)(Gx), and get the following Ga and ¬Ga for some a.
What I have got:

[image: Proof]

Can I use the negation introduction(¬I) below? If not, what should I do?

Comment: You should read up on contradiction.

Comment: Depends on your particular system of natural deduction, but in many, yes, you'd be able to infer $\bot$ and then (since $\bot$ does not involve the variable $a$), discharge the assumption using $\exists$E

Comment: Please learn to use MathJax from https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: $Ga$ shouldn't be a sub assumption of $\exists x Gx$.  You should create an entirely standalone proof of $\forall x \lnot Gx$, then later make the assumption $\exists x Gx$ and show it leads to a contradiction.  You could technically do it in either order, but it will be easier to do 2 stand alone proofs rather than 1 combined proof.

Comment: What is your $\exists$ elimination rule?  Is it $\dfrac{\exists x Px,~Py \to Q}{Q}$ or is it $\dfrac{\exists x Px}{Pc,~c\text{ is a constant}}$ ?

Answer (score 3):

The details will depend on your particular system of natural deduction. But in many, yes, you can introduce  $\bot$ with an absurdity rule  and then (since $\bot$ does not involve the variable $a$), discharge the assumption using $\exists$E, and *then* use RAA i.e. $\neg$I.

So this, for example, is a correct proof:

> $\forall x \neg Gx\\ \quad\quad|\quad \exists x Gx\\ \quad\quad|\quad\quad\quad|\quad
>  Ga\\ \quad\quad|\quad\quad\quad|\quad \neg Ga\\ \quad\quad|\quad\quad\quad|\quad \bot\\
>  \quad\quad|\quad \bot \\ \neg\exists x Gx$

Make sure you understand the justification for each step!